# How to tell if Google Chrome has a text input box focused under Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, winapi, focus, caret

On a Windows application, I want to check whether the foreground window (of any process) has the text cursor blinking or not.

There seems to be a standard way of doing it using the WinApi function [GetGUIThreadInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506.aspx), as follows:
<sub>(it's C++ code, but the language is not important)</sub>

```
GUITHREADINFO threadInfo = {sizeof(GUITHREADINFO)} ;
GetGUIThreadInfo(NULL,&threadInfo) ;
bool caretState = threadInfo.flags & GUI_CARETBLINKING ; //true if the caret is blinking
```

This works perfectly for most programs but, unfortunately, not for Google Chrome, whose `threadInfo.flags` member never has the `GUI_CARETBLINKING` flag set.

Is there another way of detecting the text caret that works on Google Chrome?

For example, I know that screen readers can traverse [Chrome's accessibility tree](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/accessibility/overview.md) which exposes the contents of the window to external applications.
Is there, anywhere in this accessibility tree, information relative to the blinking caret?

---

**Edit:**
One of the comments made me realize that saying "blinking caret" could be interpreted as if I wanted to literally detect the graphical element known as blinking caret.
That's not my intention. What I'm trying to do is to detect what the blinking caret implies, which is that a text input field is focused.

Comment: Most web browsers don't use standard Win32 controls for their UIs, particularly in the areas where content is displayed. It is not unusual for an HTML page to have hundreds/thousands of UI elements on it. Creating a separate HWND for each one would kill performance and easy up resources. So most of the UI controls, including edit fields, are likely to be custom made. That is why `GetGUIThreadInfo()` can't detect a blinking caret in a browser

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: @IInspectable, I need to provide system-wide shortcuts that work depending on whether the user is typing text or not. For example if the user wants to press Ctrl+Enter to perform some action unless he's typing, in which case Ctrl+Enter may perform some native action of the program he's typing into. That's just an example, the possibilities are countless.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I understand, however Chrome does provide some of the information in the `GUITHREADINFO` structure even though the whole Chrome GUI uses it's own rendering engine. So it seems logical to me that they could also provide the `GUI_CARETBLINKING` flag.

Comment: @GetFree `GetGUIThreadInfo()` is implemented by the OS itself. The Win32 API knows which HWND has focus, which HWND is actively showing a caret, etc. Chrome (or any other app, for that matter) does not "provide some of the information" to the Win32 API. So, unless Chrome uses real HWNDs for its edit fields, there is no way it can "provide the `GUI_CARETBLINKING` flag". That is dictated by calls to the `ShowCaret()` function, which takes an HWND as input, and is called internally by standard EDIT controls, for instance.

Comment: So this *is* an XY Problem then. What you really wish to do, is to find out, whether any particular widget the user is interacting with accepts any given input.

Comment: @IInspectable, text input specifically, not any input. The blinking caret is the only indication for the user that the focused window is accepting text input. So that's what I need to detect. If the focused window doesn't have a blinking caret it may still accept keyboard input, but it will not be text.

Comment: That doesn't sound plausible. I'd think that Microsoft Word will, in the majority of cases, accept text input. And yet, after a timeout, the cursor stops blinking. Besides not being your average caret anyway. You are trying to solve the wrong problem, basing code logic on circumstantial evidence. This is not going to produce a successful solution, until you ask the correct question.

Comment: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) is very likely a far more robust tool to employ.

Comment: @IInspectable, throughout the comments we already established that the question is not literally detecting the caret, but rather detecting if a text input field is focused. But since one situation usually implies the other I just used the blinking caret as an alias for the situation I'm trying to detect.

Comment: I'm afraid, but your simplified view is inaccurate. Microsoft Word displays something, that looks like a blinking caret, but isn't. This isn't even something you can detect. Use UI Automation, and see if that offers the tools you need to produce a robust solution. What you have set out to do simply isn't possible.

Comment: @IInspectable, I already said that the question is not literally detecting the blinking caret but what the blinking caret implies, which is that a text input field is focused. I'm already looking into Chrome's accessibility tree for that information. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: UI Automation tells you whether any particular widget has keyboard focus, and whether its role is text input. What other information are you looking for?

Comment: @IInspectable, are we talking about the same thing when I say "accessibility tree"? For example, the Microsoft program [inspect.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318521.aspx) shows the accesibility data of any UI element. Is that what you mean by "UI Automation" ?

Comment: Inspect.exe shows both information available through UI Automation, as well as the old MSAA data. If you are using inspect.exe, we are talking about the same thing.